# Button clicks and drop-down option selection for web scraping in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I've got problems with web scraping. I'm going to scrape this [website](https://www.searates.com/).
Here we have buttons, text boxes, and a dropdown list. For the  text boxes I've used these codes:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="88.0.4324.96")
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$open()
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.searates.com/")

from_textfield <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'from')$sendKeysToElement(list("Port Of Limassol, Cyprus"))
to_textfield <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'to')$sendKeysToElement(list("Port Of Mersin, Turkey"))
```

For buttons, I used the same way. However, as a result, get this error:

```
> Land <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "class", value = "_10ALxoWWyBGfz0jUBNjyCC ")

Selenium message: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '-', revision: '-', time: '-'
System info: host: '-', ip: '-', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_281'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: InvalidSelector
     Detail: The argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
     Further Details: run error details method
```

Probably, I didn't enter the HTML element correctly. *`<div class="_10ALxoWWyBGfz0jUBNjyCC "> == $0`* How can I get exact elements of html?

The same problem occurs for drop-down element selection. While applying the following codes, it only gives me FCL (which is selected while scraping), not all three options.

```
type <- remote_driver$findElements(using = "class", "_3h5YplC1TbaEavRzxwaYyK") %>% 
  lapply(function(x){x$getElementAttribute('value')}) %>% unlist
```

Does anyone have any solution to these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", "._10ALxoWWyBGfz0jUBNjyCC")`

Comment: @QHarr thank you, it works for buttons. But what about dropdown selection? Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: I will try to have another look later (exam week so not around much). I think they are dynamically updated which may mean combination of selenium actions like click and hold with tab through options, or executing some javascript. iDunno yet. Also, whilst those classes are currently fixed, they look suspiciously dynamic so you might want to consider locator strategies that don't rely on hardcoding those values.

Comment: I've solved the drop-down menu selection problem. For opening tab: ```remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "._2srCaT0ghjej5SIscfFely")$clickElement()```

To select options:
```remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "#main-filter > div > div > div._3DCtXh7PeB566R0Ry1hcgX > div:nth-child(3) > div > form > div > div._1rqpoXVt22QKC2AMMpxbmp > div > div._3IpkWWcVWLGwZTprYrAJCa > div:nth-child(1)")$clickElement()```

For changing options we need to change  ```div:nth-child(1)``` to ```div:nth-child(2)``` or ```div:nth-child(3)```.

Comment: Well done. You can likely shorten that selector.

Comment: @QHarr hi, I get a problem with text fields, site uses a text field and a drop-down menu combination. Here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67365382/how-to-web-scrape-a-text-field-drop-down-menu-combination 
Could you, please, help me?

Comment: I couldn't find `Port Of Limassol, Cyprus` and `Port Of Mersin, Turkey`